# How to trigger a callback after a redux action finishes and updates redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I learnt `React` and `Redux` about an year ago and had not used them intensively until recently. I was surprised to find out that there are quite a few changes in both `React` and `Redux`.

The first thing i noticed is that I can no longer use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method and its telling me i need to use some weird `getDerivedStateFromProps` method which doesn't really solve my current issue.

Basically, I have a register function which `dispatches` 3 `actions` - `REGISTER_REQUEST`, `REGISTER_SUCCESS` and `REGISTER_FAIL`. I also have 3 flags in my userReducer - `registering`, `registered`, `registerError`.

In my `Register` component, i want to do the following:

1. When `registering` is true, add a loading animation
2. When `registering` is false and `registered` is true, redirect the user to `/profile` route
3. When `registerError` is true, get the error from the `redux store` and set it in the component's `state`.

My first approach was the following:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    if(this.props.user){
        if(this.props.user.registered && !this.props.user.registering){
            this.props.history.push("/jobs")
        }
    }

    if(this.props.user.registerError){
        this.setState({error: this.props.user.registerErrorMessage})
    }
}
```

Which did not work out as I expected it to. As i mentioned above, its telling me that I am no longer allowed to use `componentWillRecieveProps`.

My next guess was to use the `componentDidUpdate` method but in that method, I can not call `setState` because it causes the infamous `state loop error`. I have worked around this error before but not without doing a lot of hacky things which I do not like.

I did end up solving this problem by creating a `history helper` which allowed me to redirect user from outside the component (the register function), but that ended up causing more problems with the `react router` and it did not solve my issue of setting the `registerErrorMessage` to the components `state`.

So what is the correct way of doing this in React and Redux? I am really trying to avoid using hacky tricks to get around these problems since almost always they have come around and bit me in the ass later on.

Comment: Why do you need to save the error message in component's state?

Comment: @Yousaf I already have an error field in the state from the client-side validation, and i am already using ternary conditional rendering in my jsx to render the error, so it seems like code i can reuse to keep my code clean.

Comment: that is not really the issue here, i just want to be able to do something in the component after the action is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i don't see a reason why would you need to save the error message in your component's state instead of just getting the error from the redux store and displaying it to the user, you can call `this.setState` inside `componentDidUpdate` function but to avoid the infinite cycle of state update and re-render, you need to update the state conditionally.

Assuming both `registerError` inside redux store and `error` in your component's state are initially `null`, inside `componentDidUpdate` function, check if `this.state.error` is equal to register error from the redux store or not. If they are not equal, update the state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.error != this.props.registerError) {
      this.setState({ error: this.props.registerError });
    }
}
```

#### Demo:

In [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbmwak) there's a `Register` component which dispatches an action to fetch the user from jsonplaceholder API. When HTTP request starts, `REGISTER_REQUEST` action is dispatched which sets `registering` state in the redux store to true. If user is fetched successfully, `REGISTER_SUCCESS` action is dispatched. Incase of an error, `REGISTER_ERROR` action is dispatched. When there's an error, that error is saved in the state inside `Register` component and is also displayed to the user.

To produce an error while making the HTTP request, i have changed API URL from

```
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1"     // correct URL
```

to

```
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/user/1"     // incorrect URL
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `props` change due to changes in the redux store, the component is rendered again. So you should put this logic in the `render` function. Since calling `setState` will call another render, you should just use the error value from the `props` and not save it in the state.

Comment: This was my first approach and it worked just fine, but it is not really clean, and what if there is a situation where i will absolutely have to call setState after dispatching an action? 
Why did they discontinue the componentWillRecieveProps anyway? It was useful and worked fine in my experience.

Comment: You can do some of the calculation in `mapStateToProps` to make it more clean. Can you give an example in which you have to call `setState` after an action? I can't think of a case in which you can't just use the props or have the logic in the action itself.

Comment: Like i mentioned in the comments on the original post, I already have an error property in my state object which I want to use for both client-side validation and server-side validation.

Comment: Having props.error and state.error makes it more complicated when writing the conditional render in the JSX and looks messy. What i was looking for is reusability of state.error - use it for both server and client side errors.